# Repeated measures Ancova in R

Tags: r, anova, ancova

I am trying to analyse my data but I am unsure if repeated measures ancova is the way to go.
I have a variable named "A" measured in three different conditions "1", "2" and "3" (the sample size between groups is unequal). I also have a continues covariate measured just once in the first moment.

My r code until now is:

Rmancova <- aov (A ~ condition * moment * covariate + error(id/moment)

Any help would be deeply appreciated it as I am very unsure!

I did try ezAnova in R but it didn't help me as it doesn't incorporate covariates yet.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I infer that by the "moments" you mean the observation times. How many observation times are there, are those times the same for all individuals, and do you have complete data for all individuals at all the same times? Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: Also note that the default `aov()` function in R might give misleading results with unequal sample sizes. If you can provide extra information in the question about your data and the hypothesis you want to test, you should be able to get some help here.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, like  MrFlick says, you should ask advise about stats in cross validated which is specialized for that area.

Just to give you a quick idea, if your covariate measured only in the `first moment`, it cannot be taken into this ANOVA model. It is neither `repeated` or `between-subjects`. Or your can run a seperate model including only the data from `moment 1`.